# exporting query result in Kusto to a storage account

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I get below error on running my kusto query(which i am still learning) in Azure Data Explorer. and the reason is result is more than 64 mb.. Now when I read the MS doc they mentioned we have something called Export which we can use to export the query result in a storage blob.. However I couldnt find any example as how we can do it? Did someone tried it? Can they provide a sample as how we can export to a storage account when my resulted set is more than 64 mb?

Here is what I have for now, I have data in an external table which I would like to query. so for example if my external table name is TestKubeLogs and I am quyering

```
external_table("TestKubeLogs")
| where category == 'xyz'
```

and then I get error as

```
The Kusto DataEngine has failed to execute a query: 'Query result set has exceeded the internal data size limit 67108864 (E_QUERY_RESULT_SET_TOO_LARGE).'
```

so now I am trying to export this data. How should I do it. I started writing this but how do I specify the category and table name.

```
.export
  async compressed
  to json (
    h@"https://azdevstoreforlogs.blob.core.windows.net/exportinglogs;mykey==",
    
  )
```

Comment: There is great documentation for ADX https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage

Comment: yup, following it and unable to export logs..docs dont have much examples to support

Answer (score 1):

You are not in the right direction.

Regardless the source of your data, whether you're querying an external table or managed table, it does not make sense to pull large data volume to your client.
What would you do with millions of records presented on your screen?

This is something that is true to all data systems.

Please read the relevant documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/resulttruncation

Comment: hmph.... I get your point that I should not export large chunk of data.. My question here is more how actually you do an export using KQL in Azure Data Explorer. If you can guide there that will be helpful. regarding my data size and requirement , it is now becoming more perevalent that Azure not be the best choice for storing and querying my data

Comment: When you want to extract large data volume from ADX to other place the recommendation is to export the data to Azure Storage and not reading it from some client. In your case, since you are querying an external table, I understand that your data is already located in the storage, so exporting it again, As Is, makes no sense.

Comment: As for your comment regarding Azure, I have no idea how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: yes thats correct but the logs what I am going to export is filtered logs from the set of logs which i am querying..so its kind of subset of data which will be stored in the storage account. I am in touch with Microsoft engineers and till now I have not received a valid response from them regarding my requirements with querying logs using Log analytics and hence the conclusion. the main question is still unanswered as how do we export?

Comment: I put a link in a comment to your post. Having said that, I'm not convinced you are using the right tools. If you don't need your data loaded to ADX, just read, filtered and storead in Azure Storage, You should consider using Spark, e.g., with Azure Databricks.

Comment: I have my scenario here.. given to Microsoft and also explained to you in my previous posts.. We need to store 400 days of kube-audit logs where we need to query 30/60 days of logs quite frequently but 400 days once in a while. We have been using Log analytics to retain logs for 400 days, but that is affecting us both on Cost and performance. One suggestion we got was to use ADX, retain 30/60 day in LA and 400 day in Storage account and query using ADX. This ws the recommendation from MS. I would like to knw what will be ur approach. We frequently face time-out error in LA while runing queries

Comment: and I have provided one of the query in one of the post where we face time out error. if you have suggesstion over how we can optimize that query . sometime it even fails for 12-hr time span..

Comment: If you are using a partitioned external table, filter by the partition and query relatively small amount of data, ADX might make sense for your scenario. Is that the case?

Comment: Few more questions: What do you mean by "once in a while"? Is it a fixed pattern, E.g., end of every month or a random usage pattern? Do you query the complete data of the last 400 days or relatively small data volume?

Comment: no its like for occasional querying like audit etc..like once or twice a year. So I will need 400 days of logs to Query for once/twice a year and 30/60 days of logs to query more frequently like couple of times in a month.

Comment: Couple of times in a **month**? Why keeping running compute when you hardly use it?  Just export your logs to Azure Storage, in Parquet format and query it with Azure Synapse Serverless / Azure Databricks. P.S. what data volume are we talking here?

Comment: its like 100 GB per day, for 400 days it will be approx 15 TB. couple of times in a month can also sometime goes like couple of times in a day or week for few clusters..Storing in Azure storage and

Comment: how is the cost we are looking when using Azure Synapse and Spark/databricks

Comment: Synapse serverless is $5 per TB. Azure Databricks - depend on the deployed Compute x Time. You could also use Synapse Spark Pool. Whatever you do it would probably be much cheaper that way. P.S. ADX is an *amazing* service. Like other services, you have to understand its main use-case and avoid forcing it on out-if-scope use-cases.

Comment: So you are saying for quyering even 30/60 days , Synapse can be an alternative. Our queries are written in Kusto which I believe cant be used in Synapse.. so that means we need to rewrite our queries in Spark? is tht correct?

Comment: Also when I send my logs to from Azure Diagnostic to Storage account, its stored in json ..I dont have any option to change it to other types like paraquet.. How do we do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245224/discussion-between-david--markovitz-and-zzzsharepoint).